# Redundant CTRL-SPACE proposal in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, templates, code, redundancy

How do I remove the redundant <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> proposal in Eclipse?

```
SWT
JPA
JAX-WS
```

etc.

**Example:**
[image]

I just need Java standard first time click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> proposal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced`
you can select what is shown by default and the cycle order.